# Connecting Rstudio to RDS - AWS

Tags: mysql, r, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm writing my thesis in DS and for that purpose I want to set up R and RDS in cloud. I have successfully set up both R and MySQL RDS and connected to the RDS thru my sequel pro.

However, I am trying to access the DB in R, but gives me this error:

> Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on '...eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)

Thanks!

PS. Already read through multiple articles and viewed YT tutorials but non talk about how to establish a connection between DB and R within AWS

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear. You have to provide your R code how you try to connect to RDS. How to replicate the issue? Can you explain step, by step, how to setup your RDS, user R, to try to connect to the RDS?

Comment: have you checked that your RDS is publicly accessible?

Comment: @WillBrobin I tried that and it worked! Thanks!